# R dplyr sum based on conditions

Tags: r, dplyr

I'm trying to use dplyr to multiply and sum one column, based on variables in other columns.

```
location = c("LBJ", "LBJ", "LBJ","LBJ") 
sample = c("100", "100", "100","100") 
sum = c(0,1,2,3) 
n = c(200,100,20,24)
df = data.frame(location, sample, sum,n)
df
  location sample sum   n
1      LBJ    100   0 200
2      LBJ    100   1 100
3      LBJ    100   2  20
4      LBJ    100   3  24
```

I would like to calculate ( (n where sum == 0) + ((n where sum == 1) / 2 ) ) / (sum of all n).

I am going to have multiple locations and samples which should act independently, so I want to use the group_by commands in dplyr.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: So what is the desired output for this sample data? I can't tell from your description what the value should be. Are you trying to summarize or mutate?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you want ?

```
library(dplyr)

df%>%group_by(location)%>%dplyr::mutate(Rate=mean(n[which(sum<=1)])/sum(n))

# A tibble: 4 x 5
# Groups:   location [1]
  location sample   sum     n      Rate
    <fctr> <fctr> <dbl> <dbl>     <dbl>
1      LBJ    100     0   200 0.4360465
2      LBJ    100     1   100 0.4360465
3      LBJ    100     2    20 0.4360465
4      LBJ    100     3    24 0.4360465
```

Comment: Or with a bit less code `df %>% 
  mutate(Rate = ((n[sum == 0] + n[sum == 1])/2)/sum(n))`

Comment: @biomiha he have multi location

Comment: Note to self: use base R ``which`` like so ``variable1[which(condition_on(variable2))]``